# Why does Import-Module create .psd1 and .psm1 files in AppData\Local\Temp?

Tags: powershell-core

I have a binary module (MyModule.dll and accompanying MyModule.psd1) installed in Documents\PowerShell\Modules. In the .psd1 file, a subset of the functions are exported using the FunctionsToExport key.

When I use Import-Module to import it into the current session, MyModule.psm1 and MyModule.psd1 are created in AppData\Local\Temp. The .psm1 file contains no actual code (this is good, as I don't want the code exposed in plaintext). Its contents are just some boilerplate text that I didn't create:

```
# Internal PowerShell function. Use F5 for debugging internal functions. F10 or F11 (single step) is not supported.
```

The issue is this new MyModule.psd1, which has some of the data from my installed .psd1 but notably lacks the FunctionsToExport key. As a result, all functions are exported into the session. Further, when I use Get-Module, I see both a binary module and a script module listed. For example:

```
ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Script     0.0.11.0              MyModule                            {Function1, Function2, Fu…
Binary     0.0.11                MyModule
```

What I want is to import my binary module and have a single module imported into the session that only exports the commands I have defined in the installed psd1 file. I don't want these AppData\Local\Temp versions.

Can anyone explain to me what is happening here and how I can achieve my goal? I have read a bit about PowerShell Compatibility (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_windows_powershell_compatibility?view=powershell-7), but I don't think it should apply because:

1. The module isn't installed in %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules.
2. I have CompatiblePSEditions = @('Core') defined in my installed .psd1 manifest.

I'm at a loss at this point. Thanks in advance for pointers in the right direction.